# How is satellite's footprint/coverage calculated?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, tracking

I was using [Orbitron - Satellite Tracking](http://www.stoff.pl/) software the other day and I saw that clicking on any of the satellites, you will see their footprint (they are usually not-ideal circles, usually ellipses), which are later used to calculate/predict where and when your location will be in the satellites coverage/footprint.

I was wondering, how is a satellite's footprint calculated mathematically and what needs to be considered when calculating it?

Comment: In general this is complicated.  You would need to know the antenna's beam pattern, and then essentially you intersect the surface of the planet with that beam pattern.  Typically you would also cut off the beam at some nonzero power.  Analytically this might be practically impossible, numerically it's just the problem of intersecting two objects, which has long ago been solved in computer graphics

Comment: Here: https://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/publications/download/80-51_ocr.pdf is a file that explains how to do it under some relatively mild simplifying assumptions

Comment: You need to know the shape and angle of the beam. This defines a cone with circular or elliptical cross section. Then you estimate the intersection of the cone with the spherical  surface of the Earth.

Comment: Is the Orbitron  footprint based on a broadcast antenna pattern for the satellite, or just on whether the satellite is above the horizon?

Comment: For the purpose of drawing contours on a map of the world, the comments made so far are sufficient.  If you are interested in the exact shape of the edge at a high degree of zoom, then the satellite is necessarily very low on the horizon, and terrain masking becomes important.  You then need to know the terrain elevation in detail, and have a good way of interpolating between points ([B-splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) have worked well for me).  Then you take your antenna beam pattern contour of interest, send out lots of rays along it, and see where they hit.

Comment: @DJohnM not sure how is Orbitron doing it

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers -- I'll place a bounty tomorrow just to see if someone else has an idea, if not, I'll be glad to accept @MichaelStachowsky answer.

Comment: I took few screenshots of three different satellites: https://imgur.com/a/TzSf49B and it seems like Orbitron is just calculating their radius depending on how far they are above the Earth's center, as explained in J. L. Lawrence's "Celestial Calculations: A Gentle Introduction to Computational Astronomy". (here: https://imgur.com/a/NLoePzC).

I might be wrong, tho!

Comment: different but related questions: [How do commercial broadcast satellites in GEO produce such carefully shaped signal footprints?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20861/12102) (answers are that it's somewhat "proprietary") and [What is OneWeb's constellation's “progressive pitch” and how does it avoid interference with Ku-band satellites in GEO everywhere on Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34923/12102)

Comment: I would guess that a *simple* program would estimate a footprint using the intersection of something like the half-power cone with the surface of the Earth. The intersection of a cone with a sphere is a pretty simple math problem ([1](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/c/c546.htm), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285144/284619), [3](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cone-SphereIntersection.html)), and with an ellipsoidal Earth a little more complicated. In the answer to the 2nd question I've linked to above you can see that we have to first decide where the antenna is pointing.

Comment: also related: [Why do these satellite antennas look so weird? (strangely shaped with little white dots…)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37957/12102)